# Multiple substrings not in column, with peewee orm

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'm using the Peewee ORM with a sqlite table. I have the following sqllite statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE  '% string1 %' or name LIKE  '%string2 %' OR name LIKE '%string3 %'
```

How can I do this in Peewee ?

Note I have read http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators , but not sure how to apply this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want:

```
MyModel.select().where(
    MyModel.name.contains('string1') |
    MyModel.name.contains('string2') |
    MyModel.name.contains('string3'))
```

Or, use case-insensitive LIKE directly:

```
MyModel.select().where(
    (MyModel.name ** '%string1%') |
    (MyModel.name ** '%string2%') |
    (MyModel.name ** '%string3%'))
```

To do a NOT IN:

```
MyModel.select().where(MyModel.name.not_in(['string1', 'string2']))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What I'm really after here is "NOT CONTAINS", so for your first example where do you put the '~' ?

Comment: `~MyModel.name.contains('string1')` or alternatively `~(MyModel.name ** '%string1%')`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the query as such, that this would work:

```
mytable.select().where(mytable.name == '%string1%' | mytable.name == '%string2%' | mytable.name == '%string1%')
```

This should work in your case.

Comment: Thank you, that gets me closer. How would you turn this into "NOT IN"

Comment: For not in you can simply use != symbol.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. You need parentheses for one, because python operator precedence will mash all that into a single boolean. Furthermore its meaningless to do exact equality with a '%' wildcard -- you need the LIKE operator. In Peewee you can accomplish this with the power operator, or simply skip the wildcards and use ".contains()". See my answer.